# Vue Launch Modal with Message

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to launch a modal window, much like a normal alert()

I am using bootstrap-vue BModal

1. How to generate Modal class from code and launch it
2. or, add modal  in the root app.vue and call it from child classes.

I found an example to but wasn't able to replicate that - https://codesandbox.io/embed/4l3w20zomw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `show()`, `hide()`, and `toggle()` component methods and here's [Link](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-show-hide-and-toggle-component-methods), but the difference here you will call `show()` method to `mounted()` hook it will call showModal method in mounted cycle so when application is hosted you will see modal like alert, example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-modal ref="myModalRef" hide-footer title="Using Component Methods">
      <div class="d-block text-center">
        <h1>Any Content here</h1>
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
      },
      hideModal() {
        this.$refs.myModalRef.hide()
      }
    },
    mounted() {
     this.showModal();
    }
  }
</script>
```